# Unplugged currency converter

Tags: xpages, teamstudio-unplugged

I'm using the Unplugged Mobile Controls and have a customised version of the UnpFlatView.

Inside the repeat control, which is bound to a view, I'm trying to display a column value from the view formatted as a currency field, with the following code :-

```
<xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[#{javascript:thisRowData.getColumnValue("Cost");}]]></xp:this.value>
    <xp:this.converter>
        <xp:convertNumber
            type="currency">
        </xp:convertNumber>
    </xp:this.converter>
</xp:text>
```

The value is displayed - but without the currency symbol.

I have also tried removing the converter and changing the format of the column in the view to currency format - but again just get the numeric value.

Any ideas how I can get a formatted currency value to display?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a conversation with Mark Dixon from Teamstudio, this is due to an issue in the current version of Unplugged (3.1.1). Unplugged needs to clone the component subtree for every row in a repeat control. The converter is not being included in the clone and, hence, the value is not being converted to a currency format.

This will be resolved in the next maintenance release of Unplugged.